# Completely restricting access to admin interface in Django

Tags: django

I have model adding custom field to my User model:

```
class Pozwolenie(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

ADMIN = 'Ad'
UZYTKOWNIK = 'Us'

typy = (
    (ADMIN, 'Admin'),
    (UZYTKOWNIK, 'Uzytkownik'),
    )
Uprawnienia = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=typy,
    default=UZYTKOWNIK)
```

How can i completly restrict access to django admin interface for certain users, depending on mine custom field contents?

Comment: IIRC, adding password protection to your app - I'm pretty sure this is covered in the online django docs

Comment: My whole django app has password restriction. I just want restrint certain users from usng admin interface.

Comment: Can you not use the `is_staff` flag on the user, since it was already built for that purpose?